# Parse xml with text and xml tags in same xml tag

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I wan't to parse a xml with java that looks something like this:

```
<sentence>This is a <a><b>long</b></a> sentence.</sentence>
<sentence>This is a second <a><b>even</b></a> longer sentence.</sentence>
```

As a result i need the whole sentence without the xml. I tried to parse this with dom4j. Calling the function element.getText() (current element is the sentence tag) i just get the sentence without the text in the nested xml tags.

Thanks for your help!
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use XPath to select all the text nodes

```
String getAllTextContent(Node node) {
  List<Node> nodes = node.selectNodes("descendant-or-self::text()");
  StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
  for ( Node n : nodes ) {
    buf.append(n.getText());
  }
  return buf.toString();
}
// usage
System.out.println(getAllTextContent(doc.selectSingleNode("//sentence")));
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep your  data in [CDATA] section in your xml tags

```
<sentence><![CDATA[This is a <a><b>long</b></a> sentence.]]></sentence>
```

Comment: The xml is not created by me...so i can't change it.